# move containers from one network to another docker-compose

Tags: docker, networking, dns, docker-compose

I have 3 containers launched using `docker-compose` file in defined `bridge` network (say network name:- ABC). Out of these, 2 containers are of my service's and 1 is of DB container. Service's containers connect to DB container by resolving DB service name defined in compose file.
Now, I would like to move these containers from network ABC to network PQR.

However, *I can't tear down the stack.*

**Steps I followed to do that are as follows-**

1. Note down subnet and gateway of existing network ABC.
2. Record the IPs of containers.
3. Detach containers from that network.
4. delete network ABC.
5. create new network PQR having same subnet and gateway as ABC.
6. Attach the existing containers with recorded IP to the network PQR.

Unfortunately, despite of applying these steps, I am not able to establish proper communication between those containers as before.
Can anyone locate  me where I'm missing?

Comment: Are you still trying to manage the containers with Docker Compose?  Can you change the network name everywhere in the `docker-compose.yml` and re-run `docker-compose up`?  Or just delete and recreate the containers with the new setup?

Comment: @DavidMaze yes , I am using docker compose to mange containers. What docker-compose does, it attaches folder name as prefix to every resources, it creates. Ex- for network ABC, network name is, <folder_name>_ABC. I have changed this folder name , so I have to change existing network name also, which I am doing by creating another network and migrating containers there.

Comment: Another option could be to use the [`docker-compose -p` option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/#use--p-to-specify-a-project-name) to override the `<folder_name>` (though you have to use it consistently).

Comment: @DavidMazeYes..but it wont chnage existing network name and existing containers details.

Comment: some sample `docker-compose.yaml` files would help here.